# Hide reference to wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I develop a website using Wordpress, then i have to hide that the site is under wordpress,( by changing all reference to WP in URLS, ..) I'm wondering if there is a technic to do that, if someone did the job can help me, or give some hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://pythoughts.com/how-to-hide-that-you-use-wordpress/) is the tutorial to hide WP URL from html source. hope this helps u.

you can use [wp-better-security](http://wordpress.org/plugins/better-wp-security/) plugin to rename URLS such as wp-admin to anything-you-want.